# Is there a way to use DslLifecycle methods of AndroidComponentsExtension in custom gradle plugin included as composite build?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my project I use custom gradle plugin to combine different linters (like detekt, cpd, android linter) and collect all reports in one place. I add plugin to my projects with includeBuild as a composite build.

Originally I used to configure `Android Linter` by setting properties of `lintOptions` after evaluation of the project.

```
class StaticAnalysisPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            setupLintForProject(target)

            // create StaticAnalysis tasks
        }
    }

    private fun setupLintForProject(project: Project) {
        project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            project.subprojects
                .mapNotNull { it.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java) }
                .first()
                .lintOptions.apply {
                        xmlReport = true
                        htmlReport = false
                        textReport = false
                        xmlOutput = project.getLintReportFile()
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun Project.getLintReportFile() = file("${rootProject.buildDir}/reports/lint-report.xml")
}
```

After updating `AGP` to `7.0+` I got this exception while configuring the project.

```
It is too late to set abortOnError
It has already been read to configure this project.
Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation,
or using the variant API.
```

Google [presented](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/gradle-and-agp-build-apis-how-to-write-a-plugin-1695b590e4ec) new API to customize the DSL Objects programmatically. It perfectly works but only if you use plugin inside `buildSrc`.

But when you try to get `AndroidComponentsExtension` inside composite plugin when configuring the project like this

```
private fun setupForProject(project: Project) {
        project.subprojects
            .mapNotNull { it.extensions.findByType(AndroidComponentsExtension::class.java) }
            .first()
            .finalizeDsl { ext ->
                ext.lint {
                    xmlReport = true
                    htmlReport = false
                    textReport = false
                    xmlOutput = project.getLintReportFile()
                }
            }
    }
```

You'll get exception because certain extension of subproject is not created yet.

But if you get `AndroidComponentsExtension` after project evaluated like this:

```
private fun setupForProject(project: Project) {
        project.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
            project.subprojects
                .mapNotNull { it.extensions.findByType(AndroidComponentsExtension::class.java) }
                .first()
                .finalizeDsl { ext ->
                    ext.lint {
                        xmlReport = true
                        htmlReport = false
                        textReport = false
                        xmlOutput = project.getLintReportFile()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

your configuration will have no effect.

So, I wonder is there a way to customize DSL objects like `Lint` in custom plugin included as composite build via `includeBuild`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're getting an error because the `com.android.library` or `com.android.application` plugin is not yet applied. So make sure to apply the necessary plugin mentioned above before calling the `finalizeDsl` method.
A minimal example to help you get started.

```
project.subprojects
        .mapNotNull { it.extensions.findByType(AndroidComponentsExtension::class.java) }
        .first().apply {
            project.pluginManager.apply("com.android.library")
            finalizeDsl { ext ->
                ext.lint {
                    xmlReport = true
                    htmlReport = false
                    textReport = false
                    xmlOutput = project.getLintReportFile()
                }
            }
        }
```